# Django Tincymce, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I added Tinymce to my django project. But now i cant start django test server. I'm getting following error.

```
(postjust)erkans-MacBook-Air:postjust erkan$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinymce/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tinymce import widgets as tinymce_widgets
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinymce/widgets.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tinymce.settings
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinymce/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    JS_ROOT = getattr(settings, 'TINYMCE_JS_ROOT',os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'tiny_mce'))
  File "/Users/erkan/Dev/Python/virtualenvs/postjust/bin/../lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 77, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I have Static_Url in my settings.

my settings.py :

```
"""
Django settings for postjust project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'jb-@(98(ew4kkociwv+2y(3799r*vug7-$g)e=6wsxigrk30=!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'blog',
    'pages',
    'tinymce'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'pages.context_processors.pages'
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'postjust.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'postjust.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

i try yo set static_url to '' and '/'. What is the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a STATIC_ROOT in your settings, not only STATIC_URL. Docs can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT)